# Change the Default HTML that CKEditor Renders

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using the [CKEditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) with my Rails 5 app. The text in CKEditor is rendering as:

```
<p>Foo</p>
```

and what I want to do is make it render as on the show view (after the record is created using CKEditor):

```
<p class="lead">Foo</p>
```

[Reading the documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html), I saw that there was a config option for `<p>`, `format_p',

So I added a `javascripts/ckeditor/config.js` file based on the [documentation](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#custom-toolbars-example):

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.format_p = { element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'lead' } };
}
```

In application.js, I have this:

```
//= require_directory .
```

However, it's still rendering with just `<p>`.

application.js

```
//= require jquery3.min
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require popper.min
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery.slimscroll
//= require jquery.core
//= require jquery.app
//= require datatables
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require footable.min
//= require select2-full
//= require moment
//= require datepicker-init
//= require daterangepicker-init
//= require daterangepicker
//= require jquery.counterup.min
//= require jquery.scrollTo.min
//= require metisMenu.min
//= require modernizr.min
//= require bootstrap-datepicker.min
//= require bootstrap-filestyle.min
//= require bootstrap-notify.min
//= require cable
//= require tags_field
//= require symbol_field
//= require waves
//= require wow.min
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_directory
```

Comment: share lines written inside application.js file

Comment: @NirajKaushal added - thanks!